# How to install analyzers from github in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, analyzer

I believe this should be relatively easy to do.  How do I install analyzers from github into visual studio 2015 that can't be found on nuget.

For example this little set for C# 6

[Dustin's Analyzers](https://github.com/DustinCampbell/CSharpEssentials)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download from here: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a4445ad0-f97c-41f9-a148-eae225dcc8a5?SRC=Home

Then Install.

If you wish to 'install' from GitHub then you will need to compile the source and install it as you would normally.

Answer (score 1):

In general, to install an analyzer that's not available via NuGet, you can either select **Project | Add Analyzer** from the main menu in Visual Studio or right-click the **Analyzers** entry in the project's references in Solution Explorer.